# Updating .settings outside of application c#

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I am building a class library that needs a `.config`, class libraries do not use an `app.config`/`web.config`. The config files can be updated after the application has deployed and we do this for updating our connection strings etc. My question is that I have a `.Settings` that I am storing the settings for my class library in, can I update this file manually after the application has been built or can this only be done by the application? E.g. change directories of a logger output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy create .config file for your class libraries, it's just XML file. U create in your class libraries class that will load that file and read setting from XML file. U can edit it from everywhere. Only thing you need to worry about is when your "APP" read that file and you change it , then u need your "APP" to read it again! That part is tricky , i suggest you use File System Watcher class for that.

Comment: @DanielLoudon [link](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml)

Comment: Its acutall an ASP.Net site, does that mean killing the site and starting it again on IIS

Comment: no, your changes on config will be updated on asp.net site on reload of landing site. you can easily test everything when u create file.